# Top-level async function returning promise before await/resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've got a top-level call to an async function that I am trying to get to work so that it works in all levels of the application:

```js
users = "SELECT * FROM users".get();
```

This calls a `String.prototype` function that is defined as follows:

```js
String.prototype.get = async function(callback = false) {
    const rows = await gt(this); // this = "SELECT * FROM users", returns a promise
    if (callback !== false) callback(rows);
    return rows;
}
```

This works when I wrap the original snippet in an **async** function, but the point is that it should manage all of the async-based programming architecture behind-the-scenes to make rapid development quicker and simpler; I don't want to have any extra `await` or `async` syntax in the call to the function.

Even more confusingly, using the `callback` functionality returns the correct set of awaited code..:

```js
"SELECT * FROM users".get(rows => {
  cl(rows); // correctly outputs the users table
});
```

...What? Why does it seem to await to call the callback function, but not the return? I'm perplexed at the moment.

**Edit**: my impression is that the above code should substitute for:

```js
(async function(){
    users = await "SELECT * FROM users".get();
})()
```

Comment: You can't do that, if you have an asynchronous function, you have to use await, or then(). One way or another you have to wait for the promise to be resolved.

Comment: @RomainBraun I just added an edit to my question as to what I mean - I am using async + await inside of the async function that is called?

Comment: If you run that second bit of code and look at the result you get, it's still a Promise

Comment: @RomainBraun on my side it's the data is to be returned (users - there's an await inside of it).

Comment: A big miss conception of `async / wait`, is that it pauses synchronise execution.  It doesn't, once you use promises, you have to stay with them.  So -> `users = "SELECT * FROM users".get();`, users will now be a promise, it cannot be anything other than a promise.  You will either need `await` again, or use `then`..

Comment: On a side note `String.prototype.get`, extending the prototypes of built in's, is not a good idea.  The only time it's a good idea, is if your making a poly-fill library.